# Bluetooth Stack Examples TI CC2567

Tags: bluetooth, msp430

I try to connect a Sensorunit to a PC and/or Smartphone via Bluetooth. On the Sensordevice is a MSP430f2131 uC and a PAN 1327. The PAN 1327 includes the CC2567 from Texas Instruments. I use Code Composer Studio and flash the uC via Spy-Bi-Wire. Are there some light examples to get an idea how the BT stack works? I have only discovered these examples: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC256x_MSP430_Bluetopia_Basic_Demo_APPS 
But they are very complex and tough to reverse engineer.

Comment: Good luck! If their Bluetooth stack is like their Bluetooth LE stack, most of the object code is built into the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the wiki?

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2567_Bluetooth_%2B_ANT_for_MSP430

It has an example using the EXP-MSP430F5438 and PAN13xx.